# CSS trapezoids and triangle stack food pyramid

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to make a basic Food pyramid with six levels, The bottom 5 layers/levels will use trapezoids and the top level will be a triangle to make up a pyramid shape.

I currently can display 2 trapezoids and one triangle but after that any sizing that I use looks extremely strange and skewed, Please see the image below for what I am trying to achieve:
[Css Food pyramid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD84Y.png)

Here is my current CSS code

```css
body {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
.shape {
    margin: auto;
}
.one {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid #EA1B07;
}
.one:hover {
    border-bottom: 60px solid #EA1B07;
}
.two {
    border-bottom: 75px solid #F4B600;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
.two:hover {
    border-bottom: 75px solid #F4B600;
}
.three {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #F9E029;
    border-left: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 1px;
}
.three:hover {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #F9E029;
}
.four {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #049DFC;
    border-left: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 60px;
    margin: auto;
}
.four:hover {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #049DFC;
}
.five {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #A77643;
    border-left: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 220px;
    margin: auto;
}
.five:hover {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #A77643;
}
.six {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #5CD533;
    border-left: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 380px;
    margin: auto;
}
.six:hover {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #5CD533;
}
```

As you can see the top three layers aren't connected properly.

Also, the fifth orange/gold (#F4B600) layer need to have some padding above and below it like the above image.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: HTML, please...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to style each shape individually you could put all 6 elements in a container which is then shaped using CSS clip-path as that shape is simply a triangle.

Here's a basic snippet which results in:
[image]

```css
.pyramid {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  width: 100vmin;
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
  background-color: gray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 1vmin;
}
.pyramid > * {
  background: pink;
}
.one {
  background-color: #EA1B07;
}
.two {
  background-color: #F4B600;
}
.three {
  background-color: #F9E029
}
.four {
  background-color: #049DFC
}
.five {
  background-color: #A77643;
}
.six {
  background-color: #5CD533;
}
```

```html
<div class="pyramid">
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
<div class="five"></div>
<div class="six"></div>
</div>
```

Obviously you'll want to decide on exactly the aspect ratios and gaps to suit your needs.